# How to use variables from gitlab-ci.yml in dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

For example there is 
`.gitlab-cy.yml` with `ENV_BACKEND_URI` variable

```
build:
  stage: build
   variables:
     ENV_BACKEND_URI: "http://localhost:4200"
  script:
    - docker-compose build
```

`docker-compose` uses `dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build-stage
...
...
...
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/dummy.sh"]
...
...
```

And I want to use this `ENV_BACKEND_URI` variable in `dummy.sh` script

For example just to echo it

```
echo $ENV_BACKEND_URI
```

How do I pass it there?

I've already tried to set it in `docker-compose.yml`

```
environment:
  - ENV_BACKEND_URI=${ENV_BACKEND_URI}
```

But it is't available in `dockerfile` nor `dymmy.sh`

Answer (score 14):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to bake the value of an environment variable into your image. Note that you rather want the opposite, i.e., build a generic image and adjust its behavior by setting environment variables. Still, both approaches are similar.

In order to bake the value of an environment variable into an image, you have to specify the value of your environment variable using the `ARG` keyword inside your Dockerfile and pass its value either via `--build-arg` when using `docker build` from the shell, or via the `args` keyword inside your compose file. Consider the following Dockerfile and docker-compose file:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine

ARG ENV_BACKEND_URI=$ENV_BACKEND_URI

RUN mkdir -p /app
RUN echo $ENV_BACKEND_URI > /app/script.sh

CMD ["cat", "/app/script.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        ENV_BACKEND_URI: "google.de"
```

Using the `ARG` keyword in the Dockerfile we state that we want to use the variable `ENV_BACKEND_URI` at build time and its value shall be equal to the value of the environment `ENV_BACKEND_URI` that we receive during building. We do so in the compose file by using the `arg` keyword.

Upon invoking `docker-compose build && docker-compose up` you will eventually see the ouput `app_1  | google.de`. If you prefer using the `docker build` command you have to invoke `docker build --build-arg ENV_BACKEND_URI=google.de --tag=foo .`
 first and then execute it by calling `docker run foo`. Both yield the same output, i.e., they print `google.de` to stdout.

For your CI/CD use case, you have to set the value of the variable inside your compose file to the value of the variable in the environment, i.e., `ENV_BACKEND_URI: $ENV_BACKEND_URI`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on a React app. After I set the environment variables in Gitlab UI, I used them in my build stage in `.gitlab-ci.yml` like this:

```
build-image:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - *TARGET_DEV
  script:
    - docker build --rm -f docker/build/Dockerfile
      --build-arg REACT_APP_FSI_IMPORT_QLIKSENSE_URL=$REACT_APP_FSI_IMPORT_QLIKSENSE_URL
      --build-arg REACT_APP_REPORT_QLIKSENSE_URL=$REACT_APP_REPORT_QLIKSENSE_URL
```

Simply declaring them worked for me at the top of the `Dockerfile`, but below `FROM`:

```
FROM ...

ARG REACT_APP_REPORT_QLIKSENSE_URL 
ARG REACT_APP_FSI_IMPORT_QLIKSENSE_URL
```

Comment: correct. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg